# Mac External drive ejects itself

Tags: permissions, mac, external-hdd, unmount, eject

I have been given an external drive that was formatted for mac to copy some files onto.

When I have freshly booted, it auto mounts and I can see the files, but when I try to copy files on or off the drive it unmounts itself. I think it may have some kind of built in security? I'm fairly new to Ubuntu (just installed 12.04 as dual boot alongside win 7, although I have used this version before on other machines)

I'm thinking I may need to use root access to change the permissions?
I did try changing permission in Nautilus when running from live usb, but it unmounted while I was looking through the properties.
I'm a little cautious to do stuff as root, although I'm sure I can manage it with a little help.
I have goggled a lot and seen Mac drives sometimes have user account permission issues.
I changed the permissions butit keeps unmounting though.

I couldn't find any examples of anyone having this problem before.

The drive is a 250gb Seagate freeagent go. I'm not sure if it was one specifically made for mac, or was formatted that way after purchase. PN:9kw2m4-500 SN:2ge1tmfo

If I could copy the files off, and format it to fat32 for maximum compatibility the owner would be very happy.

I also tried `fdisk -l` and running nautilus with `sudo`, neither could see the drive after it unmounted.

When I plug it in freshly booted, it beeps a few times (never had an external drive Beep at me before!) then the light goes on and beeping stops, at which point it auto mounts ok. Until I try to use it, hen it just unmounts again and I get an error message saying the location no longer exists. At which point it starts beeping continuously until unplugged.

Once the drive has unmounted itself it will not be detected again if I unplug it and plug it back in. It just beeps a lot. No lights. 
[edit]
I have now been able to get the device to auto mount after a wait without re-booting. Still cant seem to change permissions though.

Found a site that says the seagate freeagent go does have built in security. Although I'm having trouble finding details.
Thinking about removing the drive from its case and using my HD dock